# javascript - unexpected behaviour - Calling elements by ID

Tags: javascript

With all the sources and what I normally do to select an element by id, is to use `.getElementById("eleID")`.

But have recently observed that I no longer need to use:

```
.getElementById("eleID").someMethod
```

or refence it with a variable:

```
x = document.getElementById("eleID");
x.someMethod`
```

But instead can go directly too:

```
eleID.someMethod
```

I've searched around but can only find advice on using `.getElementById("eleID")` and when I first started could not just use `eleID.someMethod`. I have now tested this in Chrome (and in an extension) and Firefox

**I am wondering what has changed or has it changed? And why has this not been more widley discussed**

Comment: i thought this syntax was valid for `name` attribute only, not id, maybe the element you are using have the same value for name and id? (it is quite common)

Comment: @Kaddath good point, but no I am not using the name attribute in any of my code